# Why did Kant import the Greek 'nooúmenon' for describing his noumenon?

Tags: kant, terminology, noumenon

<sub>Source: p 216, *Philosophy: The Classics* (4 ed, 2014) by Nigel Warburton [PhD in Philosophy (Cambridge)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nigel_Warburton)</sub>

> Kant distinguishes between the world we experience (the
>   world of *phenomena*), and the underlying reality behind
>   it. The underlying reality consists of *noumena*, about
>   which we can say nothing at all because we have no
>   access to them. We are restricted to knowledge of
>   phenomena; noumena must for ever remain mysterious
>   to us. Hence most metaphysical speculation about the
>   ultimate nature of reality is misguided, since it purports
>   to describe features of the noumenal world, and our lot is
>   to dwell entirely in the phenomenal one.
>
> [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noumenon#Etymology) :] The Greek word νοούμενoν *nooúmenon*, plural νοούμενα *nooúmena*, is the [neuter middle-passive present participle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Greek_grammar#Participle) of νοεῖν *noeîn* "to think, to mean", which in turn originates from the word νοῦς [*noûs*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nous), an [Attic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attic_Greek) [contracted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synaeresis) form of [νόος](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BD%CF%8C%CE%BF%CF%82) nóos "perception, understanding, mind".<sup>[[3]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noumenon#cite_note-3)[[4]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noumenon#cite_note-4)</sup>

Kant's use of the [Loan Word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loanword#Linguistic_classification) 'noumenon' appears to contradict its original meaning in Greek; to what thinking or perception can *nooúmenon* refer, if humans can never perceive, understand, or think about noumena?  Did Kant intend a semantic shift?

Answer (score 4):

Kant gives the following explanation in Critique of Pure Reason, A249:

> Appearances, so far as they are thought as objects according to the unity of the categories, are called phenomena. But if I admit things which are objects merely of the understanding, and nevertheless can be given as objects to an intuition, though not to sensible intuition (given therefore *coram intuitu intellectuali* [to intellectual intuition]), then such things would be called noumena (intelligibilia [intelligibles]).

Comment: Adding the notion of an *intellectus archetypus* described in [this answer of mine](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/31683/did-kant-come-to-believe-that-we-have-access-to-things-in-themselves-after-all/31704#31704) from § 77 of the Critique of Judgement it makes perfect sense to name these objects this way, as they are for this "type of" intuition objects that *are exactly* as they are thought/understood and in the same moment the perception is not destinguishable from the thought/understanding anymore. **Noumena and intellectus archetypus in fact are one and the same concept.**