# can kantian archetypes represent a priori concepts

Tags: kant, foucault

In Michel Foucault's Folie et Déraison: Histoire de la Folie à l'âge Classique(History of Madness), he describes how society, throughout history, view(ed/s) and react(ed/s) to madness. The primary theme: madness is whatever forces us to view our own mortality (i.e. elderly, frailty, sickness of mind and body).
Could this, if seen as true, be a Kantian archetypical relfection of an *a priori* (if Kant would see the viewing of our mortality as *a priori*. I only assume he would seeing as *awe* (CPJ) was seen as *a priori*)?

To better explain: You are taking the attribution of death, through *awe*, and applying it to yourself as a concept, but it isn't your death, merely a reflection of your death, that you see in another.

Am I, therefore, correct to assess this as an *archetype* of an *a priori*?

Comment: I am not sure wether this isn't a wittgensteinian case of 'language at holiday'. First, a reference to awe would help me. As I understand it by now, it definitely is reserved to the stars above and the moral law within (5:161). Second, archetypes are exactly what our discursive understanding is *not* able to provide at all for Kant, see [this answer of mine](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/31683/did-kant-come-to-believe-that-we-have-access-to-things-in-themselves-after-all/31704#31704). Would you mind to clarify?

Comment: @Philip Klöcking In CPJ he uses awe in conjunction with the sublime, I believe, but if I am incorrect in my use of terms I will reword my entry.

Comment: First, the only hit for "awe" in a full text search was this one: "The astonishment bordering
on terror, the horror and the awesome shudder, which grip the spectator in
viewing mountain ranges towering to the heavens, deep ravines and the raging
torrents in them, deeply shadowed wastelands inducing melancholy reflection,
etc., is, in view of the safety in which he knows himself to be, not actual fear,
but only an attempt to involve ourselves in it by means of the imagination" (5:269) Did you refer to that?

Comment: Second: I agree that CPJ touches many things not touched by/in the scope of CPR. I just want to clarify what usage of the terms we are speaking about here ;)

Comment: @Philip Klöcking That's, actually, the very scene I was refering to. I haven't read it in years, but I recalled that as his reflection on the sublime. Am I incorrect in my use of awe?

Comment: Well, it really goes down to how 'archetypes' are understood. If I get your point correctly here, you are referring to aestetic ideas (ideals) as in: "From this, however, it follows that the
highest model, the archetype of taste, is a mere idea, which everyone
must produce in himself, and in accordance with which he must judge everything that is an object of taste, or that is an example of judging
through taste, even the taste of everyone." (5:232)?

Comment: @Philip Klöcking Foucault's account is a turn for society and Critique of Practical Reason speak to the same. It is demonstrated (as his book is a reference to historical accounts), a societal reaction to an unchanneled awe of something that has no threat to society.

Comment: @Philip Klöcking I suppose your example fits, in a sense, but I wanted to connect it with a societal moral dilemma.