# Kant vs Scientific Rationalism - Do we need the Ding an Sich

Tags: kant, physics, noumenon

I actually like Kant's distinction between noumena and phenomena. But I have a nagging doubt.

If we look at modern physics, appearances can be explained by entities such as atoms, electrons and quarks which are not themselves picturable. I can't say that this reality is the noumenon because by Kant's definition the noumenon cannot be known.

But the approach of scientific rationalism may undermine the idea of the Ding an Sich. Maybe we don't need it. We just keep exploring. Kant had no knowledge of modern science.

Any help here would be much appreciated. I have searched Google in vain. Has anyone written on the matter?

Comment: I'm not sure if you're equating the noumena with the Ding an Sich, but if you are, be aware that not everyone agrees they are equivalent concepts. See 'Noumenon and the thing-in-itself' on [This page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noumenon).

Comment: Science deals with what we can perceive (empiric knowledge = empiric truth), not with the Ding-an-Sich. We don't have access to it, and reaching it is not the goal of science, it is impossible. "We don't need it": correct, we don't need it IN SCIENCE, because science deals only with experience. The Ding-an-Sich is, on the contrary, a key topic in philosophy (the mother of all sciences), specifically, it is essential in metaphysics.

Comment: @RodolfoAP: Saying 'we don't need *ding an sich* **in science**' is misleading. Science is modeling, which means there must be a 'thing' we model for the model to be meaningful. If I make a model of the Grand Canyon, that model *ins't* the Grand Canyon; if no such thing as the Grand Canyon exists — no *ding an sich* — that 'model' is at best a flight of fancy, without relation to science.

Comment: Please do not confuse the noumenal realm with Ding an sich. The latter is only a friendly reminder that what we represent as object of experience is formed by our cognitive faculties, ie. the human way of representing the object in question. Ding an sich was never intended to be understood as any kind of reality. To be precise, it is a *contradictio in adjecto*, see [this answer of mine, under further evidence](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/31683/did-kant-come-to-believe-that-we-have-access-to-things-in-themselves-after-all/31704#31704). The *noumenal* is real in Kant though.

Comment: @TedWrigley, Science only models the phenomena and has no access to the noumena. Can I take your comment then as saying that the ding an sich is phenomena?

Comment: Well, do we need Kant at all? Scientific rationalism can probably get by without him. It is unclear what you are looking for. For the question to make sense you need to work from within Kantian perspective and find internal arguments for undermining *Ding an Sich*. An outside perspective does not undermine one piece in particular, it "undermines" the whole doctrine, if anything.

Comment: @DavidGudeman: Science models (approximations of) noumena through phenomena. We don't have "Newton's law of things-that-fall-down" (an expression of phenomena). We have "Newton's law of Gravity" (the noumenal force beneath the phenomena of things falling).

Comment: @TedWrigley, gravity is not a noumenal force. Noumena are things that cannot be known through the senses.

Comment: @DavidGudeman: Yes, gravity cannot be known through the senses. The *effects* of gravity can be known, but gravity itself can only be inferred. It's a theory, and a poorly understood one at that.

Comment: @TedWrigley, if the effects can be felt through the senses, then it's phenomenal. This is technical terminology. You can't just read brief descriptions and grasp all of the implications of the words.

Comment: @DavidGudeman: Please [see here](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kant-transcendental-idealism/#PhenNoum) up to where it says "But then it follows that things in themselves are noumena in the negative sense..." (first paragraph after the third quote). And please be more circumspect in your assumptions about what I do and do not know.

Comment: It is difficult to make my question clear.    I will start with the white coffee cup in front of me.   We see it's appearance, but we wonder what it is like in itself, independent of our visual and tactile apparatus.  Nowadays we can say that it is a structure made up of non-picturable atoms and sub-atomic particles.    Kant didn't have this option which is maybe why he postulated the idea of the unknowable ding an sich.....It seems that we can say either that we don't need the ding an sich, or that we can redefine the ding an sich as knowable.

Comment: Alternatively we could see atomic and sub-atomic particles as phenomena which are detected by the senses indirectly.  In this the Kantian ding and sich and transcendental idealism could still be upheld.

Comment: On reflection, it would be ridiculous to see an an electron as an appearance, behind which lurks a Ding an sich. This forces us to substitute die Welt an sich (The world in iteself) for the Ding an sich, a la Schopenhauer. In quantum mechanics electrons are not 'things' as 'things' are normally spoken of.

Comment: @TedWrigley, no offense was intended, but saying that science can investigate noumena shows that you don't know what the word means. From your own link: "Thus, the concept of a noumenon is the concept of an object that would be cognized by an intellect whose intuition brings its very objects into existence. Clearly, we do not cognize any noumena, since to cognize an object for us requires intuition and our intuition is sensible, not intellectual."

Comment: @DavidGudeman: If you start by misconstruing my posts, we're never going to get anywhere. I never said "science can investigate noumena". I suggested that science models things-in-themselves (a species of noumena) by investigating phenomena. And I'm sorry, but you're going to have to unpack how you're using that last quote. How does that support what you're saying?

Comment: @TedWrigley, do you know how to take a discussion to the discussion section? I don't see a button for it. The quote says that only God and angels can have any true thoughts about noumena. We beings whose knowledge of the word come only through sensible intuition cannot--by definition--know anything about noumena, even whether they exist. This is a matter of definition: if human beings can know true statements about something (such as that it causes an attractive force between two masses) then it is not a noumenon.

Comment: Marek, in light of the many comments your post has received, I suggest a revision or reposting of the original question.

Answer (score 2):

The thing-in-itself isn't the same as theoretical entities, i.e. entities that we cannot directly perceive but can infer from our observation. Kant doesn't, unlike some empiricists, make a sharp distinction here. When he discusses the *Third Analogy of Experience* in the *Critique of Pure Reason* he says that, although we cannot directly perceive magnetic fields due to the particular nature of our senses, we can know it perceptually due to an immediate inference from the presence of movement of iron filings. Kant, in other words, would deny that there is **any** ground for skepticism about our knowledge of magnetic fields just because they cannot be, strictly speaking, directly perceived by us ("directly perceive" is my term, not Kant's - I hope it's intuitively intelligible what I mean).

You significantly underappreciate human ingenuity before "modern science" (let's say, XX-th century science). Atoms and other such entities were postulated long before Kant to explain various phenomena. And, yes, there were some who insisted that this practice is scientifically unsound (although I see no grounds for this) or (a view which is still common) that these are merely 'convenient fictions'. But Kant holds neither of these views.

The thing-in-itself doesn't have anything to do with empirical knowledge. It can be defined the object of knowledge of pure reason, entirely independently of affection by an object which is the  cause of experience. And Kant denies such knowledge, metaphysical knowledge, but not scientific explanations which reference entities like atoms etc. which cannot be observed.

It must be said, however, that Kant himself wasn't a proponent of atomism.

Answer (score 1):

"Kant had no knowledge of contemporary science" is I think a more accurate statement than "Kant had no knowledge of modern science," because "modern" science" generally refers to science since the scientific revolution of Newton and his approximate contemporaries in other fields of empirical inquiry. Kant's project was more "grounding" science than inventing something beyond the reach of science with the agenda of keeping philosophy above science (although a case can certainly be made for the latter). I don't think he considered his metaphysics a necessary and hitherto missing piece for the continuing progress of science; I think he considered it a pat on science's back.

But the lasting value of Kant's metaphysics is most evident in what future philosophers have developed off of it. The *Ding-an-Sich* concept isn't transformed by contemporary science; it's transformed by Hegel, who tries to demonstrate that it's not a thing that exists but a thing in us that defines our investigations of existing things (much like your sentiment that we just keep exploring and finding out more). I recommend Robert Brandom's reading of Kant and Hegel. And also Quine's "Two Dogmas of Empiricism" (that explodes Kantianism as much as anything does, at the analytic/synthetic distinction pivot-point of his theoretical edifice). (Rorty on Quine in *Philosophy and the Mirror of Nature* for a more readable and less technical rendering of the point.) But my overall point is just that there's a lot more to Kantian metaphysics than a surface reading of the phenomenal/noumenal distinction.

Comment: Good reply. I read Quine's Two Dogmas of Empiricism many years ago. As far as I remember he tried to demolish the analytic/synthetic distinction. I will get back to it, and also check out Hegel's view. I will even check out Rorty.

Comment: Rorty, no, no. He carries pragmatism to a ridiculous degree.

Comment: But. if we are investigating particles, would it make sense to say the there is a thing in itself behind the electron. According to much of contemporary physicists the electron is a purely relational entity.

Answer (score 0):

The key to this problem is that the physical sciences produce *models* of the world; they do not access the world as such. When we talk about subatomic particles — proteins, electrons, neutrons, quarks, or what you will — we are applying concepts defined within a model that largely works to describe the events we see. We cannot see the particles directly, but we can see indirectly see effects on the world that we can attribute to these particles within this model, Therefore the particles are phenomena. In other words:

- We assert that a table is an 'object' because we can place a cup on it, and the cup won't fall through to the floor (as opposed to, say, a hologram of a table). If we were to make a table out of a perfectly transparent material, we could *still* assert it was an object, because we could *still* place a cup on it without the cup falling to the floor. The cup not falling as a phenomenal experience that points to the existence of an object.
- We assert that a quark is an 'object' because we can perform certain (highly technical) actions and produce consistent with the model that defined quarks. It doesn't matter that we can't 'see' them directly; like the transparent table, we see an effect that implies the existence of an object.

We don't really 'know' what's happening 'in reality' on the subatomic level. That's all *noumena*, beyond our grasp. We see certain phenomena; we build models that attempt to encapsulate that phenomena systematically; those models define arguable/argumentative objects that ostensible encapsulate meaningful elements of *Ding an Sich*. But there is always an insurmountable gap of knowledge between those modeled objects and *Ding an Sich* itself.

Comment: All current physical models are understood as approximate, but the goal of many physicists is a final, most fundamental ["theory of everything"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_everything) that would not be merely approximate in this way, at least as far as prediction is concerned. If we had such a theory, presumably it would still deal with purely mathematical properties of fundamental units (particles or strings or whatever), but would there be any good argument for thinking these units must have additional properties (metaphysical or otherwise) beyond those included in the theory?

Comment: @Hypnosifl: Physical models work because physical models whitewash irregularities under the error term. For instance, to 'truly' know the inertial moment of an object, we *ought* to know the composition and distribution of every single atom within that object: replace a carbon atom with a lead atom anywhere, and the inertial moment changes ever so slightly. But for most cases we can ignore such issues, modeling a point mass with uniform distributions and properties, because the results we get are within the error tolerances we set for ourselves.

Comment: @Hypnosifl: The more 'Grand' our Grand Theory gets, the more it becomes a whitewashed abstraction, divorced from the idiosyncratic details of the real world. Even if we get an exact understanding of how the fundamental forces interact with each other, we still have to apply it to practical uses, where the detail devils hold sway. As Ram Dass once said "I you think you're enlightened, go home a spend a weekend with your parents"; likewise, if you think you have perfect understanding, try putting it to use.

Comment: The fact that all models so far are approximations isn't a strong argument for the impossibility of an exact fundamental theory. Just as a hypothetical, imagine a world that does have such an exact mathematical rule underlying its behavior (like a [cellular automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_automaton)), but where intelligent beings would need many centuries of technological development before they could get the necessary empirical evidence to demonstrate which fundamental theory is correct. Until then, wouldn't you expect all their models to be approximate, with error terms?

Comment: @Hypnosifl: You're missing the point. An exact model is still a model. If I had an exact map of the surface of the earth, it still wouldn't be the surface of the earth. It would tell me how to get to Chicago, but I'd still have to put feet on the ground to go there.

Comment: It's not so clear an exact mathematical model is different from reality, see for example Max Tegmark's mathematical universe hypothesis. In any case, my question was whether, in the scenario where we did discover fundamental mathematical rules that were in principle sufficient for perfect predictions of all empirical observations, you would still say there is reason to think basic units like particles have any *properties* beyond the mathematical ones modeled by the theory. One could say there are no additional properties but still make a conceptual distinction between the model and reality.

Comment: @hypnosniff: It's not that I think basic particles have basic properties beyond those predicted by mathematical models (though that might be the case; I'll have to think on it). The issue is that ostensibly basic particles might only be a convenient fiction that allows us to describe something we otherwise couldn't. I mean, it's like asking whether Cartesian or polar coordinates are more 'true'. Neither is more 'true' than the other, and nowhere in the real world do we find 'coordinates' anyway.

Comment: @Ted and others. It could be argued that macro objects themselves are models. The Grand Canyon is itself a model based on our experiences. Observation is theory laden. I have doubts that there is a clear line of demarcation between the world of physics and the everyday world. It is just that in the case of an electron we may just see a flash instead of a distinct visual image.

Comment: I am beginning to feel that the main problem is the idea of the thing in itself, not that to which it applies. For example, if things in themselves are outside space and time what is to stop me from seeing things that are behind me, or anywhere.

Comment: @Marek: I think you have this sideways.  One way of thinking about *DIng an Sich* is to see it as 'what *is* in the absence of (or prior to) perception'. The Grand Canyon presumably existed before any human saw it, and will presumably still exist if humans send themselves into extinction. Humans see it, and give it a special conceptual place (a model) within their mental world: that is the GC as a 'phenomenon'. But there is a noumenon that precedes and exceeds our phenomenal experience.

Comment: @Ted I am glad you seem to admit that the Grand Canyon itself is a model. But, anyway, if the Ding an Sich is not itself in spacetime, what is to prevent us seeing all objects and not just a limited number of them. It cannot be the Ding an Sich which determines what we see. How does our spacetime mind determine what objects are available to perception at any moment.

Comment: @Marek: What do you mean by "not itself in spacetime"? That's a bizarre statement. Obviously the region we call "The Grand Canyon" exists in spacetime; we simply can't 'know' it — every crag, twig, pebble, cave. and vein of ore, at every point in its ongoing temporal development — in some absolute and unqualified sense. You're using a peculiar definition of noumena, I think...

Comment: @Ted I don't deny that the GC exists in spacetime. It's just that the Ding an Sich of the GC dosn't so exist. According to Kant space and time do not apply to things in themselves. It is our minds that impose space and time on the Ding an Sich. I sometimes wonder whether Ding an Sich refers to individual things or the whole field of things, to some general noumenon a la Schopenhauer who, perhaps unfortunately, called it Will.

Comment: @Marek: The *concepts* of space and time to not apply (because one needs a conscious, subjective mind to hold any concepts). But space and time also have *Ding an Sich* which other *Dinge an Sich* (I hope that's the right German pluralization) are subject to. The GC developed over some time scale in a definite location in space. Space and time do not apply to *positive noumena*, but Kant distinguished *Ding an Sich* as *negative noumena*, which is merely materiality that is cognitively inaccessible.

Comment: @Ted  "But space and time also have Ding an Sich which other Dinge an Sich are subject to."....I was totally unaware of that. Do you have an easy reference? Anyway it sounds tortuous.